# Is there a way to differentiate between "command" keys (ctrl, caps lock, page up, etc.) and "text" keys?

Tags: c#

Specifically I have a `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` object. Of course, you can come up with a list yourself. e.g.:

```
if(keyData != Keys.Control &&
    keyData != Keys.CapsLock &&
    keyData != Keys.PageUp
    ...) {
      // at this point all key presses are "text"
      // e.g. all the ASCII keys plus ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ?
    }
```

but I would probably miss some. Is there a right way to do this?

Comment: Do either of these help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.modifiers?view=netframework-4.8 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.modifierkeys?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ModifierKeys

Comment: @AndrewPiliser Caps Lock & Page Up/Down aren't modifiers so you can't only check them that way